# How to create a link for every product (laravel 5.5 model)

Tags: php, laravel, model

I got the Product model, and there I have a `link()` scope:

```
public function scopeLink($query) {
    $query->join('categories as children_category', 'products.category_id', '=', 'children_category.id')
        ->join('categories as parent_category', 'children_category.parent_id', '=', 'parent_category.id')
        ->select('products.*','children_category.id as children_cat_id', 'children_category.alias as children_cat_alias','parent_category.id as parent_cat_id', 'parent_category.alias as parent_cat_alias');
    return $query;
}
```

It returns a builder and it's fine, but I need to append link to every product collection. How can I do it?

Now my Product collection is:

```
0 => Product {#413 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:18 [▶]
      #original: array:18 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

I need to add to attributes my link to product. Pattern for link is:

`$parentCategory.'/'.$childrenCategory.'/'.$productSlug.'-'.$productId.'.html'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) attribute on your model to append some values to your model which will be visible when your model is `serialized` as `json`, but you will need access to those atributes you are building the url with inside of the model

```
...
protected $appends = ['url'];
...
public function getUrlAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['parentCategory'] . $this->attributes['childrenCategory']
       . $this->attributes['productSlug'] . $this->attributes['productId'] . '.html';
}
```

Comment: Did it, but how to use it in controllers? And my appends now is: `#appends: array:1 [▼
        0 => "url"
      ]`